# Numpy nd array to pandas column without []

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to transform a numpy nd array into a pandas column,
but the data is coming with brackets.

This is my np array:

```
array([[[  7.10105920e+07],
        [  9.18736320e+07],
        [  8.35562800e+07],
        [  7.16590640e+07],
        [  8.28060960e+07],
        [  6.77042000e+07],
        [  7.07195360e+07],
        [  1.04754616e+08],
        [  7.27420400e+07],
        [  7.33461760e+07],
        [  6.34156040e+07],
        [  8.00440800e+07],
```

This is how I'm sending to the dataframe:

```
predictions = pd.DataFrame()
predictions['y_test'] = Y_test[0].tolist()
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
           y_test
0    [71010592.0]
1    [91873632.0]
2    [83556280.0]
3    [71659064.0]
4    [82806096.0]
5    [67704200.0]
6    [70719536.0]
7   [104754616.0]
8    [72742040.0]
9    [73346176.0]
```

How can I remove the brackets ([])?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a 3D array. You can pass its first element to the DataFrame constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame(Y_test[0], columns=['y_test'])
Out: 
         y_test
0    71010592.0
1    91873632.0
2    83556280.0
3    71659064.0
4    82806096.0
5    67704200.0
6    70719536.0
7   104754616.0
8    72742040.0
9    73346176.0
10   63415604.0
11   80044080.0
```

A better alternative from Divakar is to use squeeze:

```
pd.DataFrame(arr.squeeze(), columns=['y_test'])
Out: 
         y_test
0    71010592.0
1    91873632.0
2    83556280.0
3    71659064.0
4    82806096.0
5    67704200.0
6    70719536.0
7   104754616.0
8    72742040.0
9    73346176.0
10   63415604.0
11   80044080.0
```

Comment: Rather than being bothered to find out the non-singleton dim, I would just use `squeeze`.

Comment: @Divakar yeah much better. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have a 3d array, you could try:

```
predictions['y_test'] = Y_test[0,:,0]

predictions

#       y_test
#0  71010592.0
#1  91873632.0
#2  83556280.0
#3  71659064.0
#4  82806096.0
#5  67704200.0
#6  70719536.0
#7  104754616.0
#8  72742040.0
#9  73346176.0
#10 63415604.0
#11 80044080.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways you could do

**Option 1.** Numpy indexing

```
predictions['y_test'] = Y_test[0,:,0]
```

**Option 2.** Flatten using list comprehension

```
predictions['y_test'] = [x[0] for x in Y_test[0]]
```

**Option 3.** Numpy flatten function

```
predictions['y_test'] = Y_test.flatten()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prediction = pd.DataFrame(Y_test.flatten(), columns=['y_test'])
prediction.head()

    y_test
    0     1.0
    1     1.0
    2     1.0
    3     1.0
    4     1.0
```